# Network Error AxiosError: Network Error at XMLHttpRequest.handleError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, axios

Getting Network Error:

> AxiosError: Network Error at XMLHttpRequest.handleError,

When I am requesting the API through Axios from localhost but when I am requesting from Postman I am getting the JSON data.

```js
const apiKey="My_API_Key"
    const url = "https://api.pexels.com/v1/search?query=laptop&per_page=6&page=1"
    const fetchPhotos = async()=>{
                const response = await Axios.get(url, {
                  header: {
                    Authorization: apiKey
                  }
                });
    const {photos} = response;       
    const allProduct = photos.map(photo => ({
    smallImage:photo.src.medium,
    tinyImage:photo.src.tiny,
    productName:faker.internet.userName(),
    productPrice:faker.commerce.price(),
    id:faker.string.uuid()
    }))
    }
```

[image: Error Screenshot]

[image]

Comment: CORS error means the server you're requesting from isn't letting your page access its resources - you need to make the request from YOUR server